# Storing object within TreeViewItem?

Tags: c#, object, silverlight-4.0, treeviewitem

I want to store an instance of a class within a TreeViewItem so that way I don't have to make the program sort through the list of possibly selected items for it.

I.e something that might look like

```
Bagel Poppyseed = new Bagel();    
TreeViewItem TreeViewPoppyseed = new TreeViewItem();
TreeViewPoppyseed.Bagel = Poppyseed;
```

So that way whenever TreeViewPoppyseed is selected, there would be no need to run a different method to get the instance of Bagel it has. It can just be like `TreeView.SelectedItem.Bagel;`

Does something like this already exist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what the `Tag` property is for, you can throw your object in there and retrieve it later.

See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.tag.aspx

Also, if your data-binding to that object, then it would be in the `DataContext` property.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a data template for the tree view item and then you can access the DataContext property to get the bound object.

in an event handler:

```
TreeViewItem tvi = (TreeViewItem)sender;
Bagel bagel = (Bagel)tvi.DataContext;
//do whatever you want with bagel and tree view item
```